# Problem with versions: Errno::ENOENT in Rails 3.1 RC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am using Rails 3.1 RC and Carrierwave 0.5.4. Don't know if this is an issue with 3.1.

I verified that the path and file exists (http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/unencoded/users/1/photos/test.gif) in my S3 bucket.

When I do:

```
Photo.first.update_attributes!(:job_state => 'processing', :remote_attachment_url => 'http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/unencoded/users/1/photos/test.gif')
```

Error I get:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /Users/Chris/Sites/site_name/tmp/uploads/20110603-1813-612-6936/small_test.gif
```

Why is Carrierwave trying to access the local dir instead of S3?

My initializer looks like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => APP_CONFIG['amazon_access_key_id'],       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => APP_CONFIG['amazon_secret_access_key']       # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket_name'                     # required
  config.fog_host       = 'http://cdn.site_name.com'            # optional, defaults to nil
  config.fog_public     = true                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

My uploader class looks like:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/users/#{model.user.id}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}s/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [53,53]
  end
  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fill => [106,106]
  end
  version :large do
    process :resize_to_fill => [212,212]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki
  # Heroku has a read-only filesystem, so uploads must be stored on S3 and cannot be cached in the public 
  # directory. You can work around the caching limitation by setting the cache_dir in your Uploader classes 
  # to the tmp directory.
  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
end
```

Full stack trace:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /Users/Chris/Sites/site_name/tmp/uploads/20110603-1827-5843-3673/small_test.gif
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:157:in `initialize'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:157:in `open'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:157:in `read'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:230:in `store'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:79:in `store!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:59:in `block in store!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:193:in `block in store_versions!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:193:in `each'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:193:in `store_versions!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/carrierwave-0d2e9ee87060/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:193:in `block in store_versions!'
... 16 levels...
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:183:in `transaction'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:168:in `block in update_attributes!'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:183:in `transaction'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:166:in `update_attributes!'
from (irb):5
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

In my uploader class, if I remove the versions, the upload succeeds without any errors.

Anyone coming across the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm, I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I switched my gem file from:

```
gem 'carrierwave', :git => 'http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave.git'
```

to

```
gem 'carrierwave', '0.5.4'
```

The problem seems to have gone away. There is something definitely wrong with the master version...

Hope this helps someone who comes across the same issue on Rails 3.1 RC and Carrierwave.

Answer (score 0):

Its your code here

```
  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
```

Your app is using that for processing the images.

Comment: I commented out this block in my uploader class. Restarted Rails server and Rails console. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Following command should do the trick. On Ubuntu it is like:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```